# Proving the correctness of alternative derivative definition

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

We know that the derivative exists as $f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. Using this, how can we prove that it is $f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$ as well? I tried the definition of the limit: If it exists, the both one sided limits do exists and equal to it as well. $$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} =\lim_{h \to 0^-}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ I think that this should easily lead to the proof, but somehow I am missing it.

Comment: In the ordinary definition of the derivative the limit means the two-sided limit. So it automatically works if you replace $h$ by $-h$. Of course, it is easy to find functions where a one-sided limit exists but not a two-sided limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take $k=-h$
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{k \to 0}\dfrac{f(x-k)-f(x)}{-k} =\lim_{k \to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x-k)}{k}$$
But k it's just a varibable name you can replace it by h now.